# How to install VMTools on Win VM Terraform

Tags: terraform, virtual-machine, vsphere

I want to install VMTools on Win VM post deploying OS using Autounattend.xml using Terraform. Can somebody help me in this?

I am using terraform and installed WIN OS VM on my vSphere server using an autounattend.xml file built inside ISO and OS is deployed without any error.
Now I'm not able to figure out to install VMTools once the OS is built. Need help in this

Comment: Normally VM Menu, Install Tools.

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried? What is your current autounattend file?